# Java: Networking / Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I'm having some issues for creating a simple socket, I'm new to this kind of stuff sorry for a simple question thanks. I tried to follow some tutorial for creating Sockets in java and tried this so far

```
try {
       Socket chatSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4242);
       System.out.println("connection established");    
    } 
catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm getting this kind of error

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at application.main.main(main.java:15)
```

and when I try to access my localhost from my browser I see this error

```
The connection to '127.0.0.1' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the 
target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4242
```

I have no idea what is happening because, just followed what the tutorial does. I think the issue is on my local machine but I have no idea what is making the connection refuse

Comment: What kind of aim do you have?

Comment: Do you have something on your local machine actively listening to port 4242? If so, have you tried adding a firewall rule to allow localhost connections?

Comment: We cannot access socket connections from browser. Whatever you tried in java code is client part which is tried to connect  Server socket. You should create server socket with host : 127.0.0.1 and port :4242

Comment: Creating a Socket like that would be an _out_bound connection. So your java code would try to connect to localhost:4242. What you want is to _listen_ for connection requests on 4242. So you need a [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html). Once it accepts a Client, you will have a Socket to communicate bidirectionally.

Comment: @Wufo i just want to follow the tutorial i've read("Head First Java") to be able to send message to the server but got stuck to this kind of error

Comment: @arnoldemzi Do you have a link for the tutorial?  Sending message to server 
implied having a server (ServerSocket) and a client (socket) - like Fildor mentioned

Comment: The error messages are an evidence that you have not server listening on port 4242 on your local machine... Did you really set up one?

Comment: thanks guys for all the helpful comments i get it know so basically i need a serversocket to set up server side connection thats accepts client side request.

@SergeBallesta nope and thats the problem hihi sorry i'm not good in this kind of stuff thanks btw for the comments :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP just missed a basic point and have explicitely said that the remarks in the comments were enough to understand its mistake.

Comment: I think this will help you .. [socket programming](https://www.javatpoint.com/socket-programming)